# Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout) Selenium Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I've seen a few posts related to timeout errors within Selenium.  This is becoming more and more unbearable as it's rendering my test pack unusable.  I'm testing a webpage currently in development.

I have a regression suite of around 300 test scenarios which has always worked until the latest update to firefox and selenium webdriver.  Now for almost every other test i'm getting:

`Net::ReadTimeout (Net::ReadTimeout)` errors.

This can't be coincidence.  Would anyone know of what could be causing the sudden timeout problems?  I've tried going back to previous versions of webdriver and firefox.

Comment: It started to work again for me with FF32 and the `selenium-webdriver`-gem v2.43.0. Which versions do you use?

Comment: I'm using FF32.0.3 and webdriver 2.43.0.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of 'luck' then. My FF 32.0.3 does work (on Ubuntu 14.04).

Comment: I'm finding that it's timing out at the same place everytime during automation, yet running manual tests do not encounter this problem.  That's what is pointing me toward Selenium

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you get to solve it?

Comment: It was environmental. My Webops guys tweaked the server. There was a bottleneck effect when loading some filter results.

Comment: To add, I also stopped using Selenium through Firefox.  I used Chromedriver and that did show an improvement.  I would recommend trying that

Answer (score 13):

Another option to use [RSpec::Retry](https://github.com/NoRedInk/rspec-retry) which adds a retry option for intermittently failing specs.

```
require 'rspec/retry'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # show retry status in spec process
  config.verbose_retry = true
  # Try twice (retry once)
  config.default_retry_count = 2
  # Only retry when Selenium raises Net::ReadTimeout
  config.exceptions_to_retry = [Net::ReadTimeout]
end
```

Comment: Just added rspec-retry gem for pesky Net::ReadTimeout errors on Codeship and it did the trick!

Answer (score 10):

The default timeout is 60 seconds.  One thing to try is to adjust the [internal timeout](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#internal-timeouts) to see if that fixes it:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
  client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
  client.timeout = 120 # instead of the default 60
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, profile: profile, http_client: client)
end
```